# Date Format - Java

Tags: java, datetime

I want to accept a Date format according to an ISO (can't remember which one)...

```
2009-09-17T13:03:00
```

How do I do this? I'm currently using a SimpleDateFormat but when I run my unit test against it, it fails.

```
DateFormat df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```

Unit Test is passing it this string:

```
String test1 = "2009-09-17T13:07:01";
```

Comment: Can we see the code of your unit test as well as the method which is tested?

Comment: Actually reading error messages is apparently a lost art...

Comment: The ISO standard in question is ISO 8601

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh. "Illegal Patten Character T" doesn't explain how to rectify the problem.

Comment: However, it tells you exactly where the problem is, and looking at the API do (which does tell you what to do) is the obvious next step. And if you don't know how to interpret an error message, at the very least *include it in your question*. Or provide the actually failing code rather than mutilated fragments that wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I can see your point but unfortunately we don't live in an ideal world. It seems like the majority of users did not have a problem in understanding the question, so I don't see why it matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SimpleDateFormat parameter should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss".

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You need to enclose the T in single quotes

Answer (score 4):

Your format is wrong. It should be something like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy Solution is to remove the "T" ;-)

```
...      
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");

Date date = df.parse("2009-09-17T13:07:01".replace("T",""))
```

Regards, Jan